# Тест Selenium не находит элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Тестирую ресурс https://auth.aragorn.xyz/sign-in

код

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="drivers/geckodriver")
driver.get("https://auth.aragorn.xyz/sign-in")
elem_push = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
```

Ссылку открывает, всё ок.
Но не находит ни один элемент. Ни кнопку, ни поля. Id элементов в коде есть. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Задержку надо ставить. Страница еще до конца не загрузилась, а он уже искал элемент

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "signin-button"))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте без задержки, но с таким ожиданием елемента

```
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#signin-button'))).click()
```